# Check any combination of defined enum constant is valid

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums

Given I have enum type defined as below

```java
public enum CarTypeEnum {
    SEDAN(1),
    CABRIO(2),
    ELECTRIC(4),
    ...;

    private final int carType;

    private CarType(int carType) {
        this.carype = carType;
    }

    public int getCarType() {
        return carType;
    }
}
```

And a class with an int value representing carType:

```java
public class Car {

    private String id;

    private int carType;
}
```

I know how to check for either one of the defined values in `CarTypeEnum`:

```java
public boolean isValid(int carType) {

   return value == CardType.SEDAN.getType()
      || value == CardType.CABRIO.getCarType()
      || value == CardType.ELECTRIC.getCarType();
}
```

However, I need to ensure that the `carType` int value can be **any** combination of valid enum values defined in `CarTypeEnum`:

So, it could be 1, 2, 3=(2+1), 4, 5=(4+1), 6=(4+2), 7=(4+2+1), ...

Comment: I think it would be better to use an `EnumSet` instead of an `int`.

Comment: You are describing bit flags. Now that you know the term, you can google for it ;) You can use bitwise operations to check if a specific value is included in the `int` that contains the flags.

Comment: Yup, figured that out.  I find once you figure out the name of the term, then it gets easier.  Already provided my solution in answer below.  It uses bitwise operations.  Not sure if it is what is considered by "flags" term.  Mind taking look at my answer and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with another approach by using **EnumSet**

```java
public boolean isValid(Integer value) {

    EnumSet<CarTypeEnum> enumSet = EnumSet.noneOf(CarTypeEnum.class);

    for(CarTypeEnum carType: CarTypeEnum.values()) {
        if ((value & carType.getRequestType()) == carType.getRequestType())
            enumSet.add(carType);

    }

    return enumSet.isEmpty() ? false : true;
}
```

In this approach, I create an empty `enumSet` first.

Next I navigate through all existing values in my `CarTypeEnum` and do a bitwise AND (&) operation to determine if a given value is a match and if so, I add it to `enumSet`.

Then simply check if `enumSet` is empty or not.